# how to I Convert a particular character Integer Element To Integer?

Tags: c++

Now Question is: `atoi(c[i])` is dose not convert into integer? But why ? If we can convert `char` integer with help of `atoi` then why we can't convert character particular index value?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //int num = 1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||0;
    
    char c[100];
    int ar[50];
    cin >> c;
    //cout << strlen(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(c); i++) {
        if (c[i] >= '0' && c[i] <= '9') {
            ar[i] = atoi(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Because `atoi` is used for strings, not for characters. Use `c[i] - '0'` for single `char` conversion.